# How to find roots of $x^n -a$ =0

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

This is a question which i came across while trying some problems in abstract algebra. This question was not asked directly but It is useful while attempting questions.

> Consider then equation $x^n -a$ =0. Then How 1 can find the roots of this equation.

What comes to mind is that this equation has n roots by Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and if I had $x^n -1=0$ instead of $x^n-a = 0$ then I could straight away use De Moivre's theorem and roots will be given by
$\cos(\pi /n ) + i \sin(\pi /n)$  and n=0, 1,2,...,n-1.  So, here along the same lines I can assume that $x^n -((a)^n){^{1/n}}$=0 , but there is a difference that $((a)^n )^{1/n}$ =x has n roots and so $x^n -((a)^n)^{1/n}$ =0 .

So, Can you please in detail explanation tell me what are the roots of $x^n -a$=0 which clear reason behind them.

Comment: Ever hear about the roots of unity?

Comment: $x^n=a$ is most easily solved by plugging in $x=r \cdot e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Ya that's why I used De morvie's Theorem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=r e^{i\phi}$, ehere $r>0$ and $0\le\phi<2\pi$ are real.

Then $$x=r^{\frac1n}e^{i\frac{\phi+2k\pi}n},$$ where $k=0,\dots,n-1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I see you know how to find roots for $x^n-1=0$. Now you have $x^n-a=0$.

If $a\ge 0$, then you can write
$$
z^n-1=0, \quad z=\frac{x}{\sqrt[n]{a}}. 
$$

The case when $a<0$ can be reduced to $x^n+1=0$. Now you can focus on this one. To apply the De Moivre's formula, note that
$$
-1=\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi). 
$$